# delete(0, END) doesn't work for me

Tags: python, tkinter

delete(0, END) does not work for some reason. It does not give any error messages and the rest of the code seems fine. The delete(0, END) won't delete the 0's I get in my entry boxes from the intvar and I cant figure out why it won't work. I'm using delete in another code and it works there. Could anyone help me out?

The code i got problem with.

```
    part1_entry = tk.Entry(Frame1, font=('Helvetica', 12, 'bold'), 
    textvariable=self.a3, validate = 'key', validatecommand = vcmd, width = 11)
    part1_entry.grid(column=0, row=6, sticky=(W), columnspan=1)
    part1_entry.delete(0, END)    

    part2_entry = tk.Entry(Frame1, font=('Helvetica', 12, 'bold'), 
    textvariable=self.a5, validate = 'key', validatecommand = vcmd, width = 11)
    part2_entry.grid(column=0, row=6, sticky=(E), columnspan=1)
    part2_entry.delete(0, END)
```

Here is my code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import io
from tkinter import filedialog
E=tk.E
W=tk.W
N=tk.N
S=tk.S
VERTICAL=tk.VERTICAL
END=tk.END


class Demo1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.Frame = tk.Frame(self.master, borderwidth=10)
        self.Frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))

        button1 = tk.Button(self.Frame, text="Special Rk märkning",  command=self.new_window, width = 25)
        button1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(W, E), columnspan=4)
        button2 = tk.Button(self.Frame, text="Billerud kabelmärkningar",  command=self.new_window, width = 25)
        button2.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=(W, E), columnspan=4)   



    def new_window(self):
        Billerud(self)

class Billerud:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        top1 = tk.Toplevel()
        top1.title("Billerud")
        top1.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        #fönster designern här bästems fönster ramar, rader och columner
        Frame1 = tk.Frame(top1)
        Frame1.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S), padx=5, pady=5)
        Frame1.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        Frame1.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        #Koden är en del av entry's endast nummer restriktion
        vcmd = (Frame1.register(self.validate),
             '%d', '%i', '%P', '%s', '%S', '%v', '%V', '%W')

        #create text editor
        self.text_entry = tk.Text(Frame1, width=25,height=20) 
        self.text_entry.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(W, E))
        scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(Frame1, orient=VERTICAL)
        scrollbar.grid(column=0, row=0,  sticky=(N, E, S))

        # koppla ihop listbox med scrollbar
        self.text_entry.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        scrollbar.config(command=self.text_entry.yview)

        self.a1 = tk.StringVar()
        self.a2 = tk.StringVar()
        self.a3 = tk.IntVar()
        self.a4 = tk.StringVar()
        self.a5 = tk.IntVar()

        text1 = tk.Label(Frame1, text="Kabelnamn:", font=("Helvetica", 12, "bold")).grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=(W), columnspan=2)
        Kabelnamn_entry = tk.Entry(Frame1, font=('Helvetica', 12, 'bold'), textvariable=self.a1)
        Kabelnamn_entry.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=(W, E), columnspan=2)

        text2 = tk.Label(Frame1, text="Kabelnummer:", font=("Helvetica", 12, "bold")).grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=(W), columnspan=2)
        Kabelnummer_entry = tk.Entry(Frame1, font=('Helvetica', 12, 'bold'), textvariable=self.a2)
        Kabelnummer_entry.grid(column=0, row=4, sticky=(W, E), columnspan=2)

        text3 = tk.Label(Frame1, text="Parter från:  Till:", font=("Helvetica", 12, "bold")).grid(column=0, row=5, sticky=(W), columnspan=1)

        part1_entry = tk.Entry(Frame1, font=('Helvetica', 12, 'bold'), textvariable=self.a3, validate = 'key', validatecommand = vcmd, width = 11)
        part1_entry.grid(column=0, row=6, sticky=(W), columnspan=1)
        part1_entry.delete(0, END)    

        part2_entry = tk.Entry(Frame1, font=('Helvetica', 12, 'bold'), textvariable=self.a5, validate = 'key', validatecommand = vcmd, width = 11)
        part2_entry.grid(column=0, row=6, sticky=(E), columnspan=1)
        part2_entry.delete(0, END)    

        button1 = tk.Button(Frame1, text="Make",  command=self.funktion, width = 16)
        button1.grid(column=0, row=7, sticky=(W, E), columnspan=4)   

        button2 = tk.Button(Frame1, text="Spara",  command=self.file_save, width = 16)
        button2.grid(column=0, row=8, sticky=(W, E), columnspan=4)

        top1.update()
        top1.resizable(width=False, height=False)     
        top1.mainloop()

    def validate(self, action, index, value_if_allowed,
                       prior_value, text, validation_type, trigger_type, widget_name):
        if text in '0123456789.-+':
            try:
                float(value_if_allowed)
                return True
            except ValueError:
                return False
        else:
            return False

    def file_save(self):                 
        file = tk.filedialog.asksaveasfile(defaultextension=".txt", mode='wt', filetypes = (("txt files","*.txt"),("all files","*.*")))  
        if file:
            data = self.text_entry.get('1.0', END+'-1c')
            file.write(data)
            file.close()

    def funktion(self):
        value1 = (self.a1.get())
        value2 = (self.a2.get())
        value3 = (self.a3.get())
        value4 = (self.a4.get())
        value5 = (self.a5.get())

        for parts in range(value3-1, value5):
            print('{}-{}-{}-{}\n'.format(value1, value2, parts+1, parts+1))
            self.text_entry.insert(END, '{}-{}-{}-{}\n'.format(value1, value2, parts+1, parts+1))
            self.a4.set('{}-{}-{}-{}\n'.format(value1, value2, parts+1, parts+1))

    def close_windows(self):
        self.master.destroy()

def main(): 
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Demo1(root)
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW")
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Could you reduce your code to a minimal example?

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: @Danieldarko No.... a small example is normally 10 lines of code (max) but that you can run by yourself to test it.

Comment: well then i dont know how to reduce it. i would have to change a lot of it to get it working in only 10 lines.

Comment: See the [mcve] page in the help center, or [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) (in particularly the "Tricks for Trimming" section) for guidance on building minimal reproducers appropriate to isolating an issue. Keep in mind that the only "it" that needs to be working in 10-20 lines is your bug; there's no reason to include anything that isn't directly related to the specific problem this question exists to ask about.

Answer (score 0):

lucky for you I have way too much free time at the moment.
Try using:

```
self.a3.set("")
self.a5.set("")
```

maybe someone who actually knows tkinter will be able to help more.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try:

```
part1_entry.delete(0, 'end')
part2_entry.delete(0, 'end')
```